# Preview is not responding since OS X Mavericks update

Tags: macos, preview

Preview is not responding for me since the OS X Mavericks update. I cannot open JPEG images. If I try to go to full screen view, I just get the beachball and have to hard reboot. I am a photographer and use this feature extensively to check images. This worked fine before upgrade to OS X Mavericks.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to try when encountering something like this is to move the preferences files to a new folder. I usually put them on the Desktop.

First, Quit Preview and then go to the Finder and move these files to the Desktop:

- `/Users/<short user name>/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview`
- `/Users/<short user name>/Library/com.apple.preview.*`

Run Preview and see if it is fixed.

In the case of Preview, there probably isn't any information in these files that you will really miss, It should be stuff like the previously viewed files, and whatever is in the "Preferences" dialog.

Comment: I was having a different problem which, elsewhere, the solution was "reinstall OS X." I tried this, and it solved my crashing-Preview problem. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Glad I could help.

Comment: I was also having a similar problem, and though I had not ~/Library/com.apple.preview.* directory, removing the ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview was sufficient to fix my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is to repair disk permissions (advisable after a system update). A third option is to download and manually reinstall the same [combo update](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macos) as the last update.

Answer (score 0):

So I basically just right clicked the Preview application and went to Options and a window will pop up of your Applications. I believe Preview should be highlighted. Then right click it and click Package Contents. Then click Contents and there will be another window with files on there. There you should find MacOS. Click MacOs and Terminal should be in that folder. After opening Terminal try testing to see if you can open images with Preview. It should work, you don't need to have Terminal open in order to use Preview. You should be able to open these images after going through these steps. To sum it up Right Click Preview>Options>Right Click Preview>Package Contents>Contents>MacOs>Terminal. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked. Can you elaborate on how this solves the problem of Preview getting unresponsive when opening JPGs?

Answer (score -2):

Delete:
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.LSSharedFileList.plist